# Falha na conexão Android SQLServer

Tags: android, sql-server

Erro ao tentar conectar Android/Java com SQLServer 
Segue o erro:

`The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "Socket closed". ClientConnectionId:585cb5bb-b518-461a-98b5-fb1ffae0e37b`

Já coloquei os Drivers certos. mas não consigo resolver esse problema de SSL.

Answer (score 2):

Para resolver problemas SSL com SQLServer ( especialmente para os clientes android : JDBC driver não pode ser utilizada de forma eficaz no sistema operacional Android, infelizmente) tentar usar JDTS : http://jtds.sourceforge.net/

• Confira isto sobre o seu erro:
[Link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jdbcteam/the-driver-could-not-establish-a-secure-connection-to-sql-server-by-using-secure-sockets-layer-ssl-encryption)

• Confira também este Microsoft JDBC Blog post:
[Link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jdbcteam/)

Font: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18620869/the-driver-could-not-establish-a-secure-connection-to-sql-server-by-using-secure